# arcobjects can't draw dynamic draw screen objects

Tags: arcobjects

I enabled the map to allow dynamic objects

Then I grab the IDynamicDisplay from an event which I wired up.

```
void dynamicMapEvents_AfterDynamicDraw(esriDynamicMapDrawPhase DynamicMapDrawPhase, IDisplay Display, IDynamicDisplay dynamicDisplay)
{
if (DynamicMapDrawPhase != esriDynamicMapDrawPhase.esriDMDPDynamicLayers) return;
IDynamicDrawScreen m_dynamicDrawScreen = dynamicDisplay as IDynamicDrawScreen;
m_dynamicDrawScreen.DrawScreenText(myPoint, "Test"); 
}
```

"Test" should be drawn on the screen but its not.  I have the feeling I'm missing one line of code somwhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to load the glyph into symbol properties, then you can draw it vis a vis dynamicCompoundMarker.